# stop the title showing up on hover with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I basically am storing some data in the title attribute of some divs that I probably shouldn't be. Anyways I have done it now and when I hover over these elements this information pops up in the browsers handy default tooltip.

e.g

```
<div title="blah blah blah">something</div>
```

Is there a method to stop this tooltip title functionality from working as it normally does?

Comment: guess it's a browser thing? you can't stop the tooltip.

Comment: it must be a browser thing. i didn't think so :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the `title` attribute from your HTML element and store it elsewhere.

jQuery provides a way to store information sticked to HTML elements using `$().data()`.

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('[title]').each(function()
    {
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).data('title', title).removeAttr('title');
    });
});
```

You can retrieve it later using `$(this).data('title')`

Answer (score 9):

You can move that data from the title to another attribute and use it from there.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[title]').each(function() {
      $(this).attr('data', $(this).attr('title'));
      $(this).removeAttr('title');
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using HTML attributes, you could store the information using [`$().data()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Internals/jQuery.data)

Answer (score 2):

Zed and Vincent are right.

If you want it as a jquery function (it removes the title attribute while mouse is over it, and it restores it when it leaves) to be included in a multipage script:

```
    (function($) {
        $.fn.tooltipSuppress = function() {
            $(this).hover(
                function() {
                    $(this)
                        .data('title', $(this).attr('title'))
                        .removeAttr('title');
                }, 
                function() {
                    $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('title'));
                }
            );
        }
    })(jQuery);
```

Then just call this to the elements you want it applied:

```
    $('div,someOtherSelector,ecc').tooltipSuppress();
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you should probably store the data in another field than the title.
To answer your question about hiding the title hover, have a look at [clueTip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/) (or directly at the [js](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/jquery.cluetip.js)). It replaces the standard tooltips with fancy versions, if it can do that I'm sure it can be tweaked to display nothing instead.